# Replacing columns with same attribute in the result of a SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the somewhat confusing title, I don't know how to really phrase this.

The problem I would like to solve is, for example, I have 2 tables, `GAMES` and `PLAYERS`. `GAMES` has `GAME_ID`, `PLAYER_1_ID`, `PLAYER_2_ID` and `WINNER_PLAYER_ID`. `PLAYERS` has `PLAYER_ID` and `PLAYER_NAME`. I wish to get a returned table of `GAME_ID`, `PLAYER_1_NAME`, `PLAYER_2_NAME`, `WINNER_NAME`, **essentially replacing the ID columns** from the `GAMES` table **with names**.

I think I can do it this way, but it looks too unnecessarily long:

```
select
  GAME_ID,
  PLAYER_1_NAME,
  PLAYER_2_NAME,
  WINNER_NAME
from
  (
    select
      temp2.*,
      PLAYERS.PLAYER_NAME as WINNER_NAME
    from(
        select
          temp1.*,
          PLAYERS.PLAYER_NAME as PLAYER_2_NAME
        from
          (
            select
              GAMES.*,
              PLAYERS.PLAYER_NAME as PLAYER_1_NAME
            from
              GAMES
              inner join PLAYERS on GAMES.PLAYER_1_ID = PLAYERS.PLAYER_ID
          ) temp1
          inner join PLAYERS on temp1.PLAYER_2_ID = PLAYERS.PLAYER_ID
      ) temp2
      inner join PLAYERS on temp2.WINNER_PLAYER_ID = PLAYERS.PLAYER_ID
  )
```

Am I doing it right, and is there a better and more efficient way to solve this problem?

Example:

GAMES table:

```
GAME_ID | PLAYER_1_ID | PLAYER_2_ID | WINNER_PLAYER_ID
1       | 1           | 3           | 3
2       | 2           | 3           | 3
3       | 1           | 3           | 1
```

PLAYERS table:

```
PLAYER_ID | PLAYER_NAME
1         | Tom
2         | Sam
3         | Lucy
```

What's expected to be returned:

```
GAME_ID | PLAYER_1_NAME | PLAYER_2_NAME | WINNER_PLAYER_NAME
1       | Tom           | Lucy          | Lucy
2       | Sam           | Lucy          | Lucy
3       | Tom           | Lucy          | Tom
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Just added a concrete example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, a solution for your problem is below;

```
SELECT GAME_ID,
  P1.PLAYER_NAME AS PLAYER_1_NAME,
  P2.PLAYER_NAME AS PLAYER_2_NAME,
  P3.PLAYER_NAME AS WINNER_NAME
FROM GAMES G 
LEFT JOIN PLAYERS P1 ON G.PLAYER_1_ID = P1.PLAYER_ID 
LEFT JOIN PLAYERS P2 ON G.PLAYER_2_ID = P2.PLAYER_ID 
LEFT JOIN PLAYERS P3 ON G.PLAYER_3_ID = P3.PLAYER_ID
```

After the example you shared, I'm sure this is the exact result.